# Ant Design Form Item with Autocomplete has height too big

Tags: forms, reactjs, antd

Why is the form item height so huge, here's the form item and screenshot:

```
        <Form.Item>
          { getFieldDecorator('country', {
                  rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select country!' }]
              })(
                <AutoComplete
                    dataSource={["India", "USA"]}
                    placeholder="Country"
                    filterOption={(inputValue, option) =>
                        option.props.children.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1}
                 />
            )
          }
        </Form.Item>
```

[image]

Comment: looks like its being affected by some other css in your app

Comment: maybe, to fix it I need to add `style={{height: '32px'}}` prop in `AutoComplete` component. default height is `100%` when inspected in developer tool

Comment: I noticed its coming from `height: auto` on `.ant-select-auto-complete.ant-select .ant-select-selection--single`